# How to set session flashdata when CodeIgniter controller has finished executing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want my CI controller to save flashdata for the next page load, every time it has finished executing. Here's what I've tried:

**Using `post_controller` hook:**

Initially I was trying to use the `post_controller` hook for this, but that doesn't get fired if `redirect()` has been called to immediately send the user to the next page.

**Using controller `destruct()` method:**

I then tried to use the controller's `destruct()` method to call the session `set_flashdata()` method, but that doesn't work because it looks as though the database connection has already been scrapped by that point, as the `is_object($this->conn_id)` test in the `escape_str()` method of the driver class fails.

How can I make sure a call to `set_flashdata()` is always executed on completion of a controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how much my answer is appropriate to your question.

If you use `post_controller` hooks, it will not work in case of redirect.
Even `destruct()` will not work for same case.

Image a c++ program with `constructor` and `destructor` with a exit in the middle. As the flow breaks, `destructor` will not get called.

So to get rid of this, you have following options

1. You need to find out exit points and manually and call `set_flashdata()`.
2. You can create `pre_controller` hook and call `set_flashdata()`. Depending on url get elements you can set `set_flashdata()`. It means that you need to pass something in url **extra**.